# How can I confirm that firebase notification was actually sent (fcm)?

Tags: php, jquery, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I allow users to send notifications out through my website. The notifications are working, however, I would like a way to actually confirm if the notification was sent out (in code), or if that is not possible at least confirmation that the curl worked, so I can show a message on my website that it either succeeded or failed. In my jquery post request, the status seems to always be "success", even if I provide an invalid API_ACCESS_KEY in my php (so it obviously is not sending the notification yet it is still saying success). How can I know for sure that the notification was sent out? Grateful for any help.

**Here is my post request in index.html:**

```
$("#send-button").click(function(){     
    if($("#send").val().length == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        $.post("php/send-notification.php",
        {
            notification_message: $("#send").val()
        },
        function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
            // status seems to always be "success" even with an invalid API_ACCESS_KEY
        });
    }
});
```

**Here is send-notification.php:**

```
<?php
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAA....AAA' );

    $msg = array
    (
        'body'  => $_POST['notification_message'],
        'vibrate'   => 1,
        'sound'     => 1,
        'badge'     => 1
    );

    $fields = array
    (
        'to'            => "/topics/global",
        'notification'  => $msg,
        'priority'      => 'high'
    );

    $headers = array
    (
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
?>
```

Comment: Are you checking the value of `$result` anywhere? You should check the HTTP response code, and if it's 200, you should check the response body.

Comment: I am a bit confused what that means but when I try to echo $result, there is nothing (even though the notification is working and getting sent to devices).

Comment: if($result = curl_exec( $ch )) echo "worked";  this seems to always return true, even when I set a bad API_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: Well, I don't know PHP, so I can't help with this code, but you should be able to get the HTTP status code, that will tell you if the request was rejected (for example, you'll get 401 for invalid access key).

Comment: Thank you very much that helped a lot. I now have the response code, I am a bit unsure how to relay it back to my jquery request :S

Comment: Got it. Thanks again Eran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [curl_getinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php/)

to check response information, if yur status code 200 that meet everything ok.

```
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpcode == 200) {
    //everything ok
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out how to get the code now. Now that I have the response code, how can I relay that back to my index.html? Is there a way to send the response code back to my function(data, status) {} in index.html?

Comment: You can return something from php (maybe true) when status code is 200 and chek it in your ajax.

Comment: You can see the http status codes here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes
2xx are Success

Answer (score 1):

You will get Success  result in 
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
Result format will be

```
 "multicast_id": 6581315937669460028,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "0:1495111364345221%d8a1cb15f9fd7ecd"
    }
  ]
}
```