# FCM - check if notification was sent

Tags: php, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on PHP server which is sending notifications to Firebase Cloud Messaging Service. I'm using https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM .

I sent notification from PHP using sample code:

```
$notificationBuilder = new \LaravelFCM\Message\PayloadNotificationBuilder('my title');
$notificationBuilder->setBody('Hello world')
                    ->setSound('default');
$notification = $notificationBuilder->build();

$topic = new \LaravelFCM\Message\Topics();
$topic->topic('news');
$topicResponse = \FCM::sendToTopic($topic, null, $notification, null);
$topicResponse->isSuccess(); //this returns true
$topicResponse->shouldRetry(); //this returns false
$topicResponse->error(); //this returns null
```

I tried to check if notification is sent properly in two ways:
- using javascript client, but I get error - https is required and I'm working on localhost
- check in https://console.firebase.google.com under Grow -> Notifications but I can't see anything until I add iOS/Android application which I can't do at the moment (they are still in production)

I also tried to do this with CURL, I found this: [How can I confirm that firebase notification was actually sent (fcm)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363460/how-can-i-confirm-that-firebase-notification-was-actually-sent-fcm) . However I get authentication error: "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project." I use "Authorization: key=AAA...." in header. The same key I used as FCM_SERVER_KEY in laravel-fcm library and is correct because if I change it I get error.

Am I missing something or I'm really not able to see the list of sent notifications anywhere?

edit: When using curl I used wrong URL (the one from documentation, with project ID inside). Now I don't get authorization error. But question is still present.

Answer (score 0):

Check twice your payload format is proper. Use ARC[Advance REST Client] to check Notification was sent Manually.

Here is my code using curl hope it helps

```
<?php

$responsearray = sendFCMnotification($ANDROIDPUSHNOTIFYAUTHKEYFCM,$payloadFormate,$pushMessage);
if($responsearray['response']['info'] == 200){
    if ($resposeMessage && $responsearray['response']['failure'] == 1 ) {
        // here failue response 
    }else if($response['message_id'] && $responsearray['response']['success'] == 1 ){
        // here success response
    }
}

function sendFCMnotification($authCode,$message, $id) {
    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key='.$authCode,// here Assigning Authentication Key
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array ($id), // here Mobile Registration ID
            'collapse_key'=>'Test Message',
            'data' => array (
                    "payload" => $message
            )
    );  
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $res_json   = curl_exec ( $ch );
    $result     = get_object_vars(json_decode($res_json));
    $code       = array('info' => curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
    $merge1     = array_merge($code,$fields);
    $merge      = array_merge($result,$merge1);
    $reposeDet  = array('response' => $merge);
    curl_close ( $ch );
    return $reposeDet;
}
?>
```

**Payload Format:**

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
    "eGHYv_OI5ak:APA91bGM99ttwgJVZNOTC3rrkZYchYHyDDyLFIGOgDZiDXXZcYOd12nPH3cbCsokKCRozswE-nKx8tn-KY2Sw-YZ7GL117elxTOczSjaGiuk8ZI3CnsYmmn3BQ-PEHQl58PWjdUl4x56"
  ],
  "collapse_key": "",
  "data": {
    "payload": {
      "EncryptId": "SjaGiuk8ZI3CnsYmmn3BQ-PEHQl58PWjdUl4x56",
      "messagetype": "1",
      "imageurl": "",
      "url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com/mymessages/?part=RIALL",
      "message": "Someone Send Message",
      "landing": ""
    }
  }
}
```